# Using pipe operator in function which returns Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a function which returns `Observable` but I want to pipe this `Observable` and apply `filter` function and `interval` to emit one Person each 2 seconds. Can anyone tell me how excatly `pipe` operator works in this case?

`PersonService.ts`

```
 constructor() {
    this.initPersonArray();
  }

  init(): Observable<Person> {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
      this.persons.forEach(el => {
        obs.next(el);
      });
    });
  }

  initPersonArray(): Person[] {
    this.persons.push(
      new Person('Michal', 'Kowlaski', 24, new Array('plywanie', 'pilka nozna'), Sex.MALE),
      new Person('Stefan', 'Kowlaski', 20, new Array('plywanie', 'pilka nozna'), Sex.MALE),
      new Person('Jacek', 'Kowlaski', 54, new Array('plywanie', 'pilka nozna'), Sex.MALE),
      new Person('Małgorzata', 'Kowlaski', 52, new Array('plywanie', 'pilka nozna'), Sex.FEMALE),
      new Person('Katarzyna', 'Kowlaski', 84, new Array('plywanie', 'pilka nozna'), Sex.FEMALE),
      new Person('Jan', 'Kowlaski', 86, new Array('plywanie', 'pilka nozna'), Sex.MALE),
    );
    return this.persons;
  }
```

Then in `component` I call this function by

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.personService.init().subscribe(res => {
      console.log('----->', res);
    });
  }
```

Comment: And what's the problem? `this.personService.init().pipe(filter(...))`. `interval` is not an filter, it's function that returns and Observable. Maybe you want `delay` instead?

Comment: Yes but when I want to filter persons which age is > 26 it says that it can’t read property age

Comment: Can you show what you tried and it didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplilfied example:

ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
import { map, filter, take } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  person$: Observable<string>;

  people = [
    'Tomasz',
    'Piotr',
    'Anna',
    'Magda',
  ]

  ngOnInit() {
    this.person$ = interval(2000).pipe(
      take(this.people.length),
      map((i) => this.people[i]),
      filter(person => // ... filter by person prop)
    )
  }
}
```

html file

```
<div> {{ person$ | async }} </div>
```

[Live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/iterate-array-over-time)

Comment: But how can you filter people by the property which is inside the object?

Comment: just add another filter after the map, i updated my answer

Comment: One more question - this will produce the whole array each 1sec yes? What about producing each person from that array with 1 sec interval?

Comment: It will emit one person, every two seconds up to the `this.people` array length. What exactly are you trying achieve? I can give you a more detailed example if you provide more details.

Comment: @JanTestowy if my solution solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Works fine but I am just wondering why I need to have here a `map` function? Without this I get:
`ERROR in src/app/PersonService.ts(23,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<number>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Person>'.
src/app/PersonService.ts(23,12): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<number>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Person>'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Person'.`

Comment: Interval emits series of numbers so 1...2...3 and so on. We are mapping the numbers to array  elements with the map operator.